# Changing nested keys name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested, key, rename

I'm trying to avoid conflicts with Rails reserved names in a Controller that's receiving JSON.

The code:

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController

#before_action :set_origin_transaction, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:create]

def create

    total = origin_transaction_params[:total]
    outputs_value = origin_transaction_params[:origin_inputs_attributes][:output_value]
    binding.pry
    origin_inputs_addresses = origin_transaction_params[:origin_inputs_attributes][:addresses]
    origin_outputs_value = origin_transaction_params[:origin_outputs_attributes][:output_value]
    origin_outputs_addresses = origin_transaction_params[:origin_outputs_attributes][:addresses]
    puts "total: " + total + "outputs_value: " + origin_outputs_value + "inputs_addresses: " + origin_inputs_addresses 
    puts "outputs_value: " + origin_outputs_value + "outputs_addresses: " + origin_outputs_addresses

end


# This is made to avoid using reserved names of ruby (transaction, inputs, outputs, etc), we change the keys
private
    def origin_transaction_params
  params.deep_transform_keys! { |key| key == "hash" ? "origin_hash" : ( key == "inputs" ? "origin_inputs_attributes" : ( key == "outputs" ? "origin_outputs_attributes" : ( key == "addresses" ? "btcaddresses" : key))) }
  params.permit(
    :block_height, 
    :block_index, 
    :origin_hash, 
    :total, 
    :fees, 
    :size, 
    :preference, 
    :relayed_by, 
    :received, 
    :ver, 
    :lock_time, 
    :double_spend, 
    :vin_sz, 
    :vout_sz, :confirmations,
    :origin_inputs_attributes => [ :prev_hash, :output_index, :script, :output_value, :sequence, :btcaddresses, :script_type ],
    :origin_outputs_attributes => [ :value, :script, :btcaddresses, :script_type ])
    end
```

end

The error:

```
    Processing by TransactionsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"block_height"=>-1, "block_index"=>-1, "hash"=>"4f14eb3517c92221892d7b86b4e691de404dddecbcc5d6d03148de8b1a6aceb8", "addresses"=>["12onkFjRFBdmgAMW5fapaGfo8E2PWxNRbb", "191JF8jDaCCADJsjrx171fd6PE6D9YtGoi", "1MGHXDQAA4mfBSLK4Dt3QDrAXNcXaaW7JY", "1PZCBuJC53HwjVhXb5B1rA4uFhrHrqrUUC"], "total"=>183092, "fees"=>33660, "size"=>372, "preference"=>"high", "relayed_by"=>"67.205.175.175:8333", "received"=>"2017-01-02T00:59:06.751Z", "ver"=>1, "lock_time"=>0, "double_spend"=>false, "vin_sz"=>2, "vout_sz"=>2, "confirmations"=>0, "inputs"=>[{"prev_hash"=>"dcb03a8c3dc38e28376b5b97479b06c383813c3fc5bcc66fb59c4967b85436c3", "output_index"=>1, "script"=>"47304402205c1cdd0cf3f789375a6dfc0c76eba142724edda2473b235547b7275f7dd0f1c4022046ec4f0be0726d848f6ccd1467b04023897e4575988115c0ac8dbaf569fe03da012102a6237f2117e38d566581452171cff013cfee6f69d5af84fab2214350882a81d9", "output_value"=>108376, "sequence"=>4294967295, "addresses"=>["12onkFjRFBdmgAMW5fapaGfo8E2PWxNRbb"], "script_type"=>"pay-to-pubkey-hash"}, {"prev_hash"=>"9609e8f8a18a11ce54f2b726df5cee24e4589a03feef9b121be5a2eb4ce27ce0", "output_index"=>1, "script"=>"47304402207a29300f3570b5d635b344e3fdc38b3906cb7712870a4a775b4a10cb000b0b6202207ffbd30d0ad0cafb1e93253b17ab302583816c8e17d9d15114c544a6614c9e3201210314fd8f972f8d3e840dfeee629dc5bdcb81c272334c6b23ff34ccd5cbc761fadd", "output_value"=>108376, "sequence"=>4294967295, "addresses"=>["1PZCBuJC53HwjVhXb5B1rA4uFhrHrqrUUC"], "script_type"=>"pay-to-pubkey-hash"}], "outputs"=>[{"value"=>82592, "script"=>"76a91457cf668b86c09b50e1fe89fac148ba321380d54588ac", "addresses"=>["191JF8jDaCCADJsjrx171fd6PE6D9YtGoi"], "script_type"=>"pay-to-pubkey-hash"}, {"value"=>100500, "script"=>"76a914de468bcbc3c1bf0e25dd9b626c60eac3a8d8d91488ac", "addresses"=>["1MGHXDQAA4mfBSLK4Dt3QDrAXNcXaaW7JY"], "script_type"=>"pay-to-pubkey-hash"}], "transaction"=>{"block_height"=>-1, "block_index"=>-1, "hash"=>"4f14eb3517c92221892d7b86b4e691de404dddecbcc5d6d03148de8b1a6aceb8", "addresses"=>["12onkFjRFBdmgAMW5fapaGfo8E2PWxNRbb", "191JF8jDaCCADJsjrx171fd6PE6D9YtGoi", "1MGHXDQAA4mfBSLK4Dt3QDrAXNcXaaW7JY", "1PZCBuJC53HwjVhXb5B1rA4uFhrHrqrUUC"], "total"=>183092, "fees"=>33660, "size"=>372, "preference"=>"high", "relayed_by"=>"67.205.175.175:8333", "received"=>"2017-01-02T00:59:06.751Z", "ver"=>1, "lock_time"=>0, "double_spend"=>false, "vin_sz"=>2, "vout_sz"=>2, "confirmations"=>0, "inputs"=>[{"prev_hash"=>"dcb03a8c3dc38e28376b5b97479b06c383813c3fc5bcc66fb59c4967b85436c3", "output_index"=>1, "script"=>"47304402205c1cdd0cf3f789375a6dfc0c76eba142724edda2473b235547b7275f7dd0f1c4022046ec4f0be0726d848f6ccd1467b04023897e4575988115c0ac8dbaf569fe03da012102a6237f2117e38d566581452171cff013cfee6f69d5af84fab2214350882a81d9", "output_value"=>108376, "sequence"=>4294967295, "addresses"=>["12onkFjRFBdmgAMW5fapaGfo8E2PWxNRbb"], "script_type"=>"pay-to-pubkey-hash"}, {"prev_hash"=>"9609e8f8a18a11ce54f2b726df5cee24e4589a03feef9b121be5a2eb4ce27ce0", "output_index"=>1, "script"=>"47304402207a29300f3570b5d635b344e3fdc38b3906cb7712870a4a775b4a10cb000b0b6202207ffbd30d0ad0cafb1e93253b17ab302583816c8e17d9d15114c544a6614c9e3201210314fd8f972f8d3e840dfeee629dc5bdcb81c272334c6b23ff34ccd5cbc761fadd", "output_value"=>108376, "sequence"=>4294967295, "addresses"=>["1PZCBuJC53HwjVhXb5B1rA4uFhrHrqrUUC"], "script_type"=>"pay-to-pubkey-hash"}], "outputs"=>[{"value"=>82592, "script"=>"76a91457cf668b86c09b50e1fe89fac148ba321380d54588ac", "addresses"=>["191JF8jDaCCADJsjrx171fd6PE6D9YtGoi"], "script_type"=>"pay-to-pubkey-hash"}, {"value"=>100500, "script"=>"76a914de468bcbc3c1bf0e25dd9b626c60eac3a8d8d91488ac", "addresses"=>["1MGHXDQAA4mfBSLK4Dt3QDrAXNcXaaW7JY"], "script_type"=>"pay-to-pubkey-hash"}]}}
DEPRECATION WARNING: Method deep_transform_keys! is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1, as `ActionController::Parameters` no longer inherits from hash. Using this deprecated behavior exposes potential security problems. If you continue to use this method you may be creating a security vulnerability in your app that can be exploited. Instead, consider using one of these documented methods which are not deprecated: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.1/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html (called from origin_transaction_params at /var/www/html/hubble/app/controllers/transactions_controller.rb:23)
Unpermitted parameter: btcaddresses
Unpermitted parameter: btcaddresses
Unpermitted parameter: btcaddresses
Unpermitted parameter: btcaddresses
Unpermitted parameters: btcaddresses, transaction
DEPRECATION WARNING: Method deep_transform_keys! is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1, as `ActionController::Parameters` no longer inherits from hash. Using this deprecated behavior exposes potential security problems. If you continue to use this method you may be creating a security vulnerability in your app that can be exploited. Instead, consider using one of these documented methods which are not deprecated: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.1/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html (called from origin_transaction_params at /var/www/html/hubble/app/controllers/transactions_controller.rb:23)
Unpermitted parameter: btcaddresses
Unpermitted parameter: btcaddresses
Unpermitted parameter: btcaddresses
Unpermitted parameter: btcaddresses
Unpermitted parameters: btcaddresses, transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 13ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):

app/controllers/transactions_controller.rb:9:in `[]'
```

I would also like to stop using the deprecated method.

UPDATE

As suggested by @Glyoko removed a lot of wrong things:

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:create]

def create

    total = transaction_params[:total]
    binding.pry #debugging
    render status: :created
end

private
    def transaction_params
  params.permit(
    :block_height, :block_index, :hash, 
    :addresses[], #### LINE 15 ERROR
    :total, :fees, :size, :preference, :relayed_by, :received, 
    :ver, :lock_time, :double_spend, :vin_sz, :vout_sz, :confirmations,
    :inputs => [ :prev_hash, :output_index, :script, :output_value, :sequence, :addresses[], :script_type],
    :outputs => [ :value, :script, :addresses [], :script_type ])
    end
```

end

ERROR:

> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)):

app/controllers/transactions_controller.rb:15:in `[]'
app/controllers/transactions_controller.rb:15:in`transaction_params'
app/controllers/transactions_controller.rb:6:in `create'

Notice that addresses might have 1 or several addresses

Comment: Sidebar: You're encouraged to `"#{interpolate} #{strings}"` instead of `"concating" + " " + "them"`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any problem here relating to reserved keywords, though I see at least 4 things going wrong:

1) The TypeError on line 9,

2) The deprecation warning,

3) The unpermitted parameter warning, and

4) The 500 error,

The tl;dr is that the `params.deep_transform_keys!` is doing some serious dark magic for all the wrong reasons, and you should probably delete that line and rethink your approach. That `deep_transform_keys!` is definitely the reason for (2) and (3), and is possibly the reason for (1). More detailed answers, in the order I listed them:

1) The TypeError on line 9 comes from `origin_transaction_params[:origin_inputs_attributes][:output_value]`. `origin_transaction_params[:origin_inputs_attributes]` is returning some sort of non-hash object, which means you're calling `something_thats_not_a_hash[:output_value]`, which produces the TypeError. You could add protection for this in your controller, but this probably reflects a deeper problem with your data structure. (What's the JSON payload look like?)

2) As of Rails 4, `params` is now an instance of ActionController::Parameters. `params` will look and act like a hash, but it is not really a hash proper under the hood. This means that not all hash methods will work on it. In this case, `deep_transform_keys!` happens to work for now, but as the warning says, its implementation will change as of Rails 5.1 and `deep_transform_keys!` will no longer work on it. There's no way to get rid of this warning without getting rid of the call to `deep_transform_keys!`.

In fact, the proper use case of strong params is to call permit only on key names that are part of the expected payload. That is, only call permit on key names that are part of the *unaltered* JSON payload. This probably means you should in fact get rid of the `deep_transform_keys!`, as using it to alter the params hash is improper usage.

In any case, "transaction", "inputs", and "outputs" are NOT reserved keywords in ruby, and even if they were, that wouldn't stop them from being keys in a hash as long as they're quoted.

3) The deep_transform_keys! line is creating a root level key called "btcaddresses". It's not just inside origin_inputs_attributes/origin_outputs_attributes, so it needs to be permitted at the root. Again, this is only needed if you keep the deep_transform_keys! line. You really probably want to get rid of it.

4) The 500 error is coming from (1), so this would be solved once that's fixed, although you may still encounter 500's if your views aren't setup properly. If this happens, try adding something like

`render status: :created`

to the end of the create method, and make sure you have a create template in your view/ directory.

Comment: Ok I updated the initial post, deleted what you said and just have a single error related to one of the params

Answer (score 0):

everyone

Code is now working, it just still saying "Unpermitted parameter: transaction", but it's printing what I needed. I searched the JSON and there's not a single word named transaction, and same thing within the code:

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:create]

def create

    amount = btcTx_params[:total]
    btcAddresses = btcTx_params[:outputs][0][:addresses]
    confirmations = btcTx_params[:confirmations]
    double_spend = btcTx_params[:double_spend]
    puts "Bitcoin Addresses = #{btcAddresses}"
    puts "Amount = #{amount}"
    puts "Confirmations = #{confirmations}"
    puts "Is double spend? = #{double_spend}"
    #binding.pry #debugging
    render status: :created
end

private
    def btcTx_params
  params.permit(
    :block_height, :block_index, :hash, 
    :total, :fees, :size, :preference, :relayed_by, :received, 
    :ver, :lock_time, :double_spend, :vin_sz, :vout_sz, :confirmations,
    :inputs => [ :prev_hash, :output_index, :script, :output_value, :sequence, :script_type, :addresses => [] ],
    :outputs => [ :value, :script, :script_type, :addresses => [] ],
    :addresses => [])
    end
```

end

Output:

Parameters:

> {

```
"block_height":-1,
"block_index":-1,
"hash":"4f14eb3517c92221892d7b86b4e691de404dddecbcc5d6d03148de8b1a6aceb8",
"addresses":[
    "12onkFjRFBdmgAMW5fapaGfo8E2PWxNRbb",
    "191JF8jDaCCADJsjrx171fd6PE6D9YtGoi",
    "1MGHXDQAA4mfBSLK4Dt3QDrAXNcXaaW7JY",
    "1PZCBuJC53HwjVhXb5B1rA4uFhrHrqrUUC"
],
"total":183092,
"fees":33660,
"size":372,
"preference":"high",
"relayed_by":"67.205.175.175:8333",
"received":"2017-01-02T00:59:06.751Z",
"ver":1,
"lock_time":0,
"double_spend":false,
"vin_sz":2,
"vout_sz":2,
"confirmations":0,
"inputs":[
    {
        "prev_hash":"dcb03a8c3dc38e28376b5b97479b06c383813c3fc5bcc66fb59c4967b85436c3",
        "output_index":1,
        "script":"47304402205c1cdd0cf3f789375a6dfc0c76eba142724edda2473b235547b7275f7dd0f1c4022046ec4f0be0726d848f6ccd1467b04023897e4575988115c0ac8dbaf569fe03da012102a6237f2117e38d566581452171cff013cfee6f69d5af84fab2214350882a81d9",
        "output_value":108376,
        "sequence":4294967295,
        "addresses":[
            "12onkFjRFBdmgAMW5fapaGfo8E2PWxNRbb"
        ],
        "script_type":"pay-to-pubkey-hash"
    },
    {
        "prev_hash":"9609e8f8a18a11ce54f2b726df5cee24e4589a03feef9b121be5a2eb4ce27ce0",
        "output_index":1,
        "script":"47304402207a29300f3570b5d635b344e3fdc38b3906cb7712870a4a775b4a10cb000b0b6202207ffbd30d0ad0cafb1e93253b17ab302583816c8e17d9d15114c544a6614c9e3201210314fd8f972f8d3e840dfeee629dc5bdcb81c272334c6b23ff34ccd5cbc761fadd",
        "output_value":108376,
        "sequence":4294967295,
        "addresses":[
            "1PZCBuJC53HwjVhXb5B1rA4uFhrHrqrUUC"
        ],
        "script_type":"pay-to-pubkey-hash"
    }
],
"outputs":[
    {
        "value":82592,
        "script":"76a91457cf668b86c09b50e1fe89fac148ba321380d54588ac",
        "addresses":[
            "191JF8jDaCCADJsjrx171fd6PE6D9YtGoi"
        ],
        "script_type":"pay-to-pubkey-hash"
    },
    {
        "value":100500,
        "script":"76a914de468bcbc3c1bf0e25dd9b626c60eac3a8d8d91488ac",
        "addresses":[
            "1MGHXDQAA4mfBSLK4Dt3QDrAXNcXaaW7JY"
        ],
        "script_type":"pay-to-pubkey-hash"
    }
]
```

}

**Unpermitted parameter: transaction
Unpermitted parameter: transaction
Unpermitted parameter: transaction
Unpermitted parameter: transaction**

#### PUTS

Bitcoin Addresses = ["191JF8jDaCCADJsjrx171fd6PE6D9YtGoi"]

Amount = 183092

Confirmations = 0

Is double spend? = false

Rendering transactions/create.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered transactions/create.html.erb within layouts/application (0.6ms)
Completed 201 Created in 41ms (Views: 28.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

But that was hell out of an improvement.
Thanks a lot, guys

Answer (score 0):

Aaaaaand...it's done!

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:create]

def create

    amount = btcTx_params[:total]
    btcAddresses = btcTx_params[:outputs][0][:addresses]
    confirmations = btcTx_params[:confirmations]
    double_spend = btcTx_params[:double_spend]
    puts "Bitcoin Addresses = #{btcAddresses}"
    puts "Amount = #{amount}"
    puts "Confirmations = #{confirmations}"
    puts "Is double spend? = #{double_spend}"
    #binding.pry
    #binding.pry #debugging
    render status: :created
end

private
    def btcTx_params
  params.require(:transaction).permit(
    :block_height, :block_index, :hash, 
    :total, :fees, :size, :preference, :relayed_by, :received, 
    :ver, :lock_time, :double_spend, :vin_sz, :vout_sz, :confirmations,
    :inputs => [ :prev_hash, :output_index, :script, :output_value, :sequence, :script_type, :addresses => [] ],
    :outputs => [ :value, :script, :script_type, :addresses => [] ],
    :addresses => [])
    end
```

end

It needed params.require(:transaction). Now the unpermitted parametter: transaction  error is gone =) thanks a lot for your help